# Fetch data from txt file and export it to CSV

Tags: powershell

I have a below data in a text file.

```
author   ; testname1
Revision ; 121
Date     ; 10/5/2018
Path     ; dev/test1
Message  ; notes: testdata1
author   ; testname2
Revision ; 1212
Date     ; 10/6/2018
Path     ; dev/test2
Message  ; notes: testdata2
author   ; testname3
Revision ; 1213
Date     ; 10/5/2018
Path     ; dev/test3
Message  ; notes: testdata3
```

I want to read this and export to CSV which look like below.

```
author,Revision,Date,Path,Message
testname1,121,10/5/2018,dev/test1,notes: testdata1
testname2,1212,10/6/2018,dev/test2,notes: testdata2
testname3,1213,10/5/2018,dev/test3,notes: testdata3
```

Any suggestions?

I have tried below code

```
$local:InputFilePath   = "path of file"
$local:OutFilePathCSV  = "path of csv file"
$local:CSVDelimiter    = ","
$local:OutDataList     = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.Arraylist
$local:CurrentDataList = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.Hashtable

Select-String -Path $InputFilePath -Pattern "^[\s]" -NotMatch | ForEach-Object {
    $local:CurrentLine  = ($_.Line).TrimEnd()
    $CurrentLine

    $OutDataList.Add($(New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSObject -Property $CurrentDataList)) | Out-Null
    $CurrentDataList.Clear()
    if ($CurrentLine -match "^[\s]*([\w]*)[\s]+(.*)") {
        $CurrentDataList.Add($matches[1], $matches[2])
        $matches[1]
        $matches[2]

        #break
    }
}
$OutDataList |
    Sort-Object -Property Serial |
    Select-Object -Property author, Revision, Date, Action, Path |
    Export-Csv -Path $OutFilePathCSV -Delimiter $CSVDelimiter -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. You will need [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6) and [Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-6)

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow also .., figuring out a way to post the code

Comment: I am sure i tried get content and export csv and hash table .., all those stuff but no luck.

Comment: Yes, but we would **really** like to see some of _your efforts_, even if they fail so we can help you with the code.

Comment: I need to correct this below two lines  
    Select-String -Path $InputFilePath -Pattern "^[\s]" -NotMatch   
    $CurrentLine -match "^[\s]*([\w]*)[\s]+(.*)"

Comment: and ofcourse --  $CurrentDataList.Clear()   -- This line should be in the correct place. I am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right path. However, there are a couple of ways to do this. This is the easiest, most straight-forward method. However, because you have all the different columns listed individually in the input file, you will need to preemptively know, **at least**,the number of columns, and the delimiter used (here it's the semicolon).

Sticking with your example text file, and as much as your code as possible, this is how you would do it.

```
$InputFilePath     = "path of file"
$OutFilePathCSV    = "path of csv file"
$CSVDelimiter      = ","
$OutDataList       = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.Arraylist
$ColumnNumbers     = 5
$InputFileDelimter = ';'

$InputFileData = Select-String -Path $InputFilePath -Pattern "^[\s]" -NotMatch
for ($i = 0 ; $i -lt $InputFileData.count; $i += $ColumnNumbers) {
    $CurrentLine = New-Object PSObject
    for ($j = 0 ; $j -lt $ColumnNumbers; $j++) {
        if ($InputFileData[$i+$j].Line -match "^(.*)\s*$InputFileDelimter\s*(.*)\s*$") {
            $CurrentLine | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $matches[1] -Value $matches[2]
        }
    }
    $OutDataList.Add($CurrentLine)
}
$OutDataList |
    Select-Object -Property Author, Revision, Date, Action, Path |
    Export-Csv -Path $OutFilePathCSV -Delimiter $CSVDelimiter -NoTypeInformation
```

Tips/info:

- With your regex `"^[\s]*([\w]*)[\s]+(.*)"`

  - `^[\s]*` is redundant because you are already excluding lines that begin with white space in the select string.
  - `([\w]*)` will not capture columns with spaces in the name (not necessary here, but for future reference).
  - `(.*)` will capture the delimiter as well.
- With the regex `"^(.*)\s*$InputFileDelimter\s*(.*)\s*$"`

  - `^(.*)\s*` will capture full column names without the white space before the delimiter. You can swap this for `^\w*` if it will always be only one word.
  - `$InputFileDelimter\s*(.*)\s*$` will capture the entire column value, without leading or trailing white space.

Notes:

- `$CSVDelimter` isn't necessary because `Export-CSV` defaults to using a comma.
- You don't have a column named `Serial`, so the sort doesn't do anything in your code.

Hope this helps! Good luck with PowerShell!

Edit:

From the comment on another answer below: [Fetch data from txt file and export it to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856108/fetch-data-from-txt-file-and-export-it-to-csv/52858532#comment92633599_52857102)

> An alternative to a fixed read count is splitting at the first field with a RegEX using a postive look ahead $data = (Get-Content .\data.txt -Raw) -split "`n(?=author)"

This is actually a really good idea, and I like it. The only problem is that you have to be sure your first column is always listed first, per group of properties.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!!   @J. Doe

Answer (score 1):

Found a super simple way to solve your problem by creating a hashtable and exporting it to a csv:

```
#requires -Version 3

$path = 'C:\Temp\data.txt'
$data = Get-Content -Path $path -ReadCount 5

$collection = foreach ($obj in $data)
{
    $out = [ordered]@{}
    foreach ($line in $obj.Split("`n"))
    {
        $a, $b = ($line -split ';').Trim()
        $out[$a] = $b
    }
    [pscustomobject]$out
}

$newPath = 'C:\Temp\file.csv'
$collection | Export-Csv -Path $newPath -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

This solution assumes your text document is well-formed.

Comment: Thanks a lott!!   @TheIncorrigible1

Comment: An alternative to a fixed read count is splitting at the first field with a RegEX using a postive look ahead `$data = (Get-Content .\data.txt -Raw) -split "\`n(?=author)"` +1